# jquery dialog расположить в центре экрана

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

при открытии диалога он располагается в центре страницы, т.е. если она большая то окно скроллится до середины. как расположить диалог в центре видимого экрана?

Comment: окно диалога по умолчанию так и выводится. оно не выводится в середине элемента

Answer (score 0):

Используй `position: fixed` вместо `position: absolute`, и тогда модалка будет всегда по центру.